# Zeit/pkg: Cannot find module 'config'

Tags: node.js, node-modules, zeit-pkg

I've distilled this issue down to a simple test.  I'm using the node "config" module to define configuration values for my app.  Pkg doesn't complain on build, but barfs at runtime with the following message.  Am I missing something?

```
jim-macbookpro:~/development/node/pkgtest$ ./pkgtest-macos
pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1172
      throw error;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'config'
1) If you want to compile the package/file into executable, please pay attention to compilation warnings and specify a literal in 'require' call. 2) If you don't want to compile the package/file into executable and want to 'require' it from filesystem (likely plugin), specify an absolute path in 'require' call using process.cwd() or process.execPath.
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:540:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1269:46)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:470:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:583:17)
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1153:31)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/snapshot/pkgtest/index.js:1:78)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1243:22)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:650:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:558:32)
```

index.js is simple:

```
const config = require('config');
console.log('yo:', config.message);
```

and I have a default.json in the local 'config' directory:

```
{
    "message": "whodapunk?"
}
```

My package.json, for what it's worth:

```
{
    "name": "pkgtest",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "config": "^1.30.0"
    },
    "bin": "index.js"
}
```

Comment: Yo, I have the exact same problem. Any joy at all?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was because my config file was added to `.gitignore` -- as soon as I removed it from there it worked like a charm!

Comment: Hmmm.  I definitely have my config file checked in.  Not sure why that matters.  Did you possibly change something else at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. However not a really beautiful solution I managed to find a way to work around it.

When calling pkg I do not set e NODE_ENV. Then in my entry point I check if a NODE_ENV is set. If not I define the variables I need there.

```
let port = null;
let db = null;
let name = null;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  const config = require('config');
  port = config.get('port');
  db = config.get('database');
  name = config.get('name');
} else {
  port = 3000;
  db = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/production';
  name = 'Server Production';
}
```

I tried linking directly to the config module but after that it started complaining that it could not find and files in my config folder. This worked for me as a work around.